# Vim automatically removes indentation on Python comments

Tags: python, vim, indentation

I'm using Vim and editing Python scripts.

Autoindent works pretty well in general, but when I start a new line and type '#' to type a comment, Vim unindents that line for me.

For example, if have

```
def foo():
```

and I press enter, Vim will indent properly

```
def foo():
    pass
```

but, if instead of typing `pass`, I type `#`, it unindents automatically

```
def foo():
# comment

class Thing():
    def __init__(self):
         pass
# comment line gets unindented all the way
```

my .vimrc file follows.  anyone know why this is happening?

```
set tabstop=4
set smartindent
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set scrolloff=3
set statusline=%f%m%r%h%w\ [%Y\ %{&ff}]\ [%l/%L\ (%p%%)]
set laststatus=2
```

Comment: For teh search engine: dedent, outdent.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Setting `smartindent` on makes Vim behave like you describe for me, whereas with `nosmartindent` (which is what I tend to use) it behaves like you'd prefer it to.

Update: From the docs on `smartindent`:

> When typing '#' as the first character in a new line, the indent for
>   that line is removed, the '#' is put in the first column.  The indent
>   is restored for the next line.  If you don't want this, use this
>   mapping: ":inoremap # X^H#", where ^H is entered with CTRL-V CTRL-H.
>   When using the ">>" command, lines starting with '#' are not shifted
>   right.

That seems to be it.

---

Update: Probably no need to bother with the following... I'll leave it here for the added informational value. ;-)

If setting `nosmartindent` doesn't help, perhaps you could use the `:set` command -- with no parameters -- to obtain the list of all settings in effect in your Vim session, then paste it somewhere (on [Pastie](http://pastie.org/) perhaps). There's a few other options which affect automatic indentation, as far as I remember.

Comment: I had difficulty getting the ^H suggested in this answer using CTRL-V CTRL-H, but I found that `inoremap # X<BS>#` does the trick.

Comment: You can also use `inoremap # X<c-h>#` if you really want the CTRL-H

Comment: I tried this and @zzart answer's but it doesn't fix it competently.  If you already have an unidented `#`, the `>>` command won't change the indent.

Answer (score 22):

While Michał's post explains what smartindent does, you can do a lot better than just turning it off. You could configure it more to your liking, or better yet, let Vim pick better indentation for you. With the following in your vimrc instead of other indent settings:

```
filetype indent on
```

Vim will automatically use the proper indent plugin for python. This is way better than just not de-indenting a # line - pretty much everything should be properly indented.

Comment: Jefromi,

I don't understand your answer.  vim is already selecting the python indentation plugin - the problem is that the plugin happens to indent illogically, removing indentation completely.  So your proposed solution doesn't fix the problem as explained in the question.

Comment: `smartindent` will cause line-initial `#` to unindent regardless of whether `filetype indent` is turned on or not. So, you have to set `nosmartindent` to fix things anyway.

Comment: Ah, right. I should clarify: I really meant using filetype indent *instead of* other indent settings.

Comment: And Thomas, I was thrown off by you saying that `autoindent` was working well - that's an option setting, separate from the filetype indent plugins (though I believe the python indent plugin enables autoindent, because it gets half the job done).

Comment: ...and the fact that you didn't have any mention of `filetype` in your .vimrc.

Comment: @Jefromi You should add more detail to this answer, it is far from being comprehensible

Comment: @SaulloCastro You should add more detail to your comment: what is incomprehensible? Was it just that I hadn't incorporated the discussion from the comments? If you use filetype-based indentation (the vimrc line I gave) Vim will automatically indent Python correctly - seems simple enough.

Comment: @Jefromi Probably due to my lack of experience in VIM I could not make it work only reading the answer. It would be nice to have some example, like `.py ident on`, or `python ident one`, or something similar

Comment: Yeah, this outright doesn't work for me. Either I am misunderstanding something, something is missing from this answer or there is something else wrong.

Comment: @DavidYoung It definitely works if the filetype in question is supported, i.e. it's correctly detected and has indentation rules (so python should be fine!), and if there's nothing else in your vimrc to confound things. If you want to troubleshoot, I'd probably ask a new question on https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: my problem is i like smartindent for `if foo:` and then getting an indent on the next line. I absolutely hate when I have a comment starting at beginning of line and I highlight code and comments and indent it and the commented lines don't indent. `filetype indent on` does not seem to indent after functions/ifs when I have `nosmartindent`, and `nocindent` also does nothing. :shrug:

Comment: wow, ok, so use `cindent` and `set indentkeys-=0#` and you can indent things again!

Answer (score 6):

You can try an option only for python files:

```
autocmd BufRead *.py inoremap # X<c-h>#<space>
```

Answer (score 4):

For some unkown reason the above behavior was caused when i had `cindent` on. Turning it off fixed it for me. None of the other fixes above helped.

Comment: The reason is that the convention in C code (which is what `cindent` is for) is to unindent a proprocessor directive, which begins with `#`. So, this is helpful for C but a big problem for Python.

Answer (score -2):

If you install this script, you will get **proper** python (pep8) indenting:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=974

Comment: This appears to be much worse.

Comment: Never mind. Even suggested answer seems to fail. Must be some plugin I have