# smartindent doesn't allow one to manually indent lines beginning with "#"

Tags: vim, auto-indent

The shortcut `>>` doesn't indent lines that start with `#` for me in either C or Python when `smartindent` is set.

If anyone has a workaround, that would be cool; I'm also posting this let people know (it was rather confusing and frustrating why that key wasn't working).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure vim to not put comments at the beginning of lines while editing python files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354097/how-to-configure-vim-to-not-put-comments-at-the-beginning-of-lines-while-editing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is discussed in a related post on SO, which refers to `:h smartindent` and recommends setting nosmartindent as a workaround.  Are you using `filetype indent on` to get the full language-dependent indenting?:

[Vim automatically removes indentation on Python comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360249/vim-automatically-removes-indentation-on-python-comments)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the behavior is expected `>>` does not work with `#` as documented in `:help smartindent`. The doc also has a work around given:

```
:inoremap # X^H#
```

where ^H is entered as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>