# Vim autoindent does not work the way I expect after 'if', 'for', 'while'; how can I make it work the way I want?

Tags: vim, auto-indent

I have auto indentation turned on in my `.vimrc` file `set autoindent` which moves to the previous indentation like so (`█` is the cursor position)

```
while (! skynet.selfAware()){
    DARPA.funding++;█
}
```

Pressing enter/carriage return will yield

```
while (! skynet.selfAware()){
    DARPA.funding++;
    █
}
```

But is there any way to make vim smart enough to realize that a new indentation is required such that starting from this

```
while (! skynet.selfAware()){█
}
```

pressing enter/carriage return will yield

```
while (! skynet.selfAware()){
    █
}
```

instead of

```
while (! skynet.selfAware()){
█
}
```

Comment: Since `autoindent` is defined to 'indent to the same level as the previous line', what you are seeking is not 'autoindent' but something else; the problem is your expectations of 'autoindent', not the behaviour of 'autoindent' itself.  FWIW, you can use 'control-T' to indent one shift width (and 'control-D' to unindent one shift width) at any time.  (A shift width need not be the same as a tabstop; I have to work with '`set ts=8 sw=4`, and then there's a difference between tab and 'control-T'.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ctrl+T/D are good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `autoindent`, use `smartindent`.  It does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: smartindent, contrary to its name, is not too smart. In Python, if I start a line with `#` it gets completely unindented. Why is that?

Comment: @puk - That's covered in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360249/vim-automatically-removes-indentation-on-python-comments

Answer (score 0):

You could try turning `cindent` on.  There are a huge number of options available for controlling how it works, see `:help cinoptions-values`.