# vim does remove indent for all lines starting with # character

Tags: vim, comments, auto-indent

I have already read this:

[Vim automatically removes indentation on Python comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360249/vim-automatically-removes-indentation-on-python-comments)

I have tried everything that is mentioned there without success:

- I have `smartindent` off
- I use `filetype indent on`
- I tried the trick with `:inoremap # X^H#`

None of the above helps: Whenever i start a indented line with a `#` the indentation is removed and the cursor is moved to column 0.

Here's the output of `:set`: https://gist.github.com/mikehaertl/5387743

And here's the `vimrc.local` that i use on Ubuntu 12.10: https://gist.github.com/mikehaertl/1612035

So i'm clueless what else i could try. I don't want my cursor to be moved to column 0 whenever i type an indented `#`. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

So i found out this is caused by `cindent`. Still this is very obscure to me: Why does vim do that and how can i prevent that from happening if i still want to use `cindent`?

Comment: can you try with a clean vim, and use only 1 module? Maybe any of the modules are creating conflict?

Comment: can you please explain a little bit what does your mapping `inoremap # X^H#` do? it seeems it just simply insert text `X^H#` And. what is your question? you want to auto un-indent comment line when you editing a py src file? or you have already a py src file(s), and you want to reformat the comment lines by removing indents ?

Comment: I've actually figured it out: It was the `cindent` that caused the problems. I've used to to get better auto indentation for PHP files.

Comment: I figured out too.. your `^H` means `ctrl-h`... (c-v c-h).....

Comment: @Kent That's from the vim help file. And what i want: I don't want that the cursor jumps to column 0 whenever i begin a indented line with a `#`. Has nothing to do with python files but happened on every file. No idea why `cindent` causes this (and what's the idea behind that behavior anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `cindent`, it probably  contains the `0#` part which comes by
default. You just have to remove it,  for example by using an  auto command to
be triggered  when the  file type changes  to the type(s)  you want  with this
indentation disabled.

Is it PHP? If so, adding this line to your .vimrc may help:

```
autocmd FileType php set cinkeys-=0#
```

Comment: Awesome! This solves another vim mistery for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MichaelHärtl Glad to help! Just to add the source, you can check `:h cinkeys-format` to see the complete keys that come set by default.

Answer (score 0):

The `'formatoptions'` option governs that behavior. What is the output of `:set fo`?

`croql` is a good value, see `:h fo-table`.

Comment: Thanks, but i could not really find anything helpful in that output. Still wonder why `cindent` affects this.

Comment: oh, and `set fo` gives `tcrqn` for me.